# Why does this core dumped error happen in my class? I’ve already included copy constructor, copy assignment, and destructor

Tags: c++, class, multidimensional-array, dynamic, coredump

It's just a 2D-array(TwoD) class with one constructor taking the number of row and the number of column, an overloaded assignment operator, and an overloaded non-member + operator as TwoD class's friend.

updated code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class TwoD{
    public:
        TwoD(){}
        ~TwoD(){
            for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
                delete [] arr[i];
            }
            delete [] arr;
        }
        TwoD(int r,int c):row(r),col(r){
            cout<<"Enter "<<r<<" rows of "<<c<<" doubles each"<<endl;
            arr=new double*[row];
            for(int i=0;i<r;i++){
                arr[i]=new double[c];
                for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
                    cin>>arr[i][j];
                }
            }
            
        }
        TwoD(const TwoD& b){
            row=b.row;
            col=b.col;
            if(b.arr==NULL){
                return;
            }
            arr=new double*[row];
            for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
                arr[i]=new double[col];
                for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
                    arr[i][j]=b.arr[i][j];
                }
            }
            
        }
        void echo() const{
            for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
                    cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }
        }
        void set(int r,int c,double value){
            arr[r][c]=value;
        }
        const TwoD& operator=(const TwoD& b);
        friend const TwoD operator+(const TwoD& a,const TwoD& b);
    private:
        int row,col;
        double** arr=NULL;
        
};

const TwoD& TwoD::operator=(const TwoD& b){
    if(this==&b){
        return *this;
    }
    
    if(arr!=NULL){
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
            delete [] arr[i];
        }
        delete [] arr;
    }
    
    row=b.row;
    col=b.col;
    arr=new double*[row];
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
        arr[i]=new double[col];
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
            arr[i][j]=b.arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

const TwoD operator+(const TwoD& a,const TwoD& b){
    TwoD temp(a);
    for(int i=0;i<a.row;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<a.col;j++){
            temp.arr[i][j]+=b.arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
int main(){
    cout<<"Enter the row and column dimensions of the array\n";
    int r,c;
    cin>>r>>c;
    TwoD a(r,c);
    cout<<"Echoing the 2 dim. array, matrix1\n";
    a.echo();

    cout<<"Enter the row and column dimensions of the array\n";
    cin>>r>>c;
    TwoD b(r,c);
    cout<<"Echoing the 2 dim. array, matrix2\n";
    b.echo();

    TwoD d;
    cout<<"Assigning matrix 2 to matrix 3\n";
    cout<<"Displaying the 2 dim array, matrix3 resulting from assignment"<<endl;
    d=b;
    cout<<"Rows "<<r<<" Cols "<<c<<endl;
    d.echo();

    cout<<"Displaying the 2 dim array, sum of matrix 1 and 2\n";
    cout<<"Rows "<<r<<" Cols "<<c<<endl;
    (a+b).echo();
    return 0;
}
```

old one:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class TwoD{
    public:
        TwoD(){}
        ~TwoD(){
            delete [] arr;
        }
        TwoD(int r,int c):row(r),col(r){
            cout<<"Enter "<<r<<" rows of "<<c<<" doubles each"<<endl;
            arr=new double*[r];
            for(int i=0;i<r;i++){
                arr[i]=new double[c];
                for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
                    cin>>arr[i][j];
                }
            }
            
        }
        TwoD(const TwoD& b){
            row=b.row;
            col=b.col;
            for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
                arr[i]=new double[col];
                for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
                    arr[i][j]=b.arr[i][j];
                }
            }
            
        }
        void echo() const{
            for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
                    cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }
        }
        void set(int r,int c,double value){
            arr[r][c]=value;
        }
        const TwoD operator=(const TwoD& b);
        friend const TwoD operator+(const TwoD& a,const TwoD& b);
    private:
        int row,col;
        double** arr;
        
};

const TwoD TwoD::operator=(const TwoD& b){
    if(this==&b){
        return *this;
    }
    delete [] arr;
    row=b.row;
    col=b.col;
    arr=new double*[row];
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
        arr[i]=new double[col];
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
            arr[i][j]=b.arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

const TwoD operator+(const TwoD& a,const TwoD& b){
    TwoD temp(a);
    for(int i=0;i<a.row;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<a.col;j++){
            temp.arr[i][j]+=b.arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
int main(){
    cout<<"Enter the row and column dimensions of the array\n";
    int r,c;
    cin>>r>>c;
    TwoD a(r,c);
    cout<<"Echoing the 2 dim. array, matrix1\n";
    a.echo();

    cout<<"Enter the row and column dimensions of the array\n";
    cin>>r>>c;
    TwoD b(r,c);
    cout<<"Echoing the 2 dim. array, matrix2\n";
    b.echo();

    TwoD d;
    cout<<"Assigning matrix 2 to matrix 3\n";
    cout<<"Displaying the 2 dim array, matrix3 resulting from assignment"<<endl;
    d=b;
    cout<<"Rows "<<r<<" Cols "<<c<<endl;
    d.echo();

    cout<<"Displaying the 2 dim array, sum of matrix 1 and 2\n";
    cout<<"Rows "<<r<<" Cols "<<c<<endl;
    (a+b).echo();
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

https://ibb.co/Csj5sH8

The echo() member function is wrong too(I don't know why), but I wanna focus on the core dump first, and what does this even mean?

Comment: `delete [] arr` only deletes `arr` itself, the allocation you made with `arr=new double*[r]`. The elements inside `arr` will *leak*.

Comment: `operator=` should return a reference. Otherwise every assignment will also create a copy that is immediately discarded, which is very wasteful.

Comment: so this for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
    delete [] arr[i];
   }
   delete [] arr; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash most likely happens because in the copy-constructor you don't allocate memory for `arr` itself.

When you do e.g.

```
arr[i]=new double[col];
```

then the variable `arr` is *uninitialized* and will be invalid. This invokes *undefined behavior* and likely a crash.

You need to allocate memory for `arr` itself first:

```
arr=new double*[row];
```

---

There is however another possible cause of a crash, and that's because a default-constructor object will have uninitialized member variables.

If such a default constructed object is used as source for a copy-operation then you will be using these uninitialized values and that will lead to *undefined behavior* and possible crashes.

And even if you properly initialize the variables, you need to add checks to make sure that you're not using null pointers etc.

Comment: wow, thanks, do you why is the memeber function echo() wrong?